# How to write a function where the coefficient tends to 0 in R?

Tags: r, function

I would like to write a function that smooths the coefficient of growth rate to 0 in 60 days. So far I managed to write the following code:

```
corona <- data.frame(Cases = c(3, 16, 79, 157, 229, 322, 400, 650, 888, 1128, 1694, 2036, 2502, 3089, 3858), Date = seq(as.Date("2020/02/20"), as.Date("2020/03/05"), by = "days"))

library(dplyr)
corona_entire <- corona %>% mutate(Growth = (Cases - lag(Cases))/lag(Cases)*100)  

mean(corona_entire$Growth[12:15])

ff = function(x) x*(1.2285823)^60

ff(3858)
```

However, in my function the growth rate (0.2285823) is constant over 60 periods. I would like to tell R to make that growth rate tend to 0 as we get closer and closer to 60. I need to write a convergence function for the growth rate basically.

Any idea how can I code it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `ff` is just a linear function in `x` with slope `(1.2285823)^60` and zero offset .Are you trying to fit an (exponential decay?) model to the `Growth`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers  I am trying to model the growth rate. Written the way I wrote it is a constant growth rate model `function(x) x*(1.2285823)^60`. I want that the growth rate (0.2285823) not to be constant but to decay over time

Comment: @asfa not quite, I would need to model the growth rate itself.

Comment: @Rollo99 *"I would need to model the growth rate itself"* So you *do* want to fit a non-linear model to the `Growth` data? As I said before, perhaps an exponential decay model `y = y0 * exp(k * time)` would work? This can be trivially linearised by taking the log, in which case you don't even need to use non-linear fitting routines and instead you can use `lm`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @MauritsEvers This is a good idea. The idea is to predict  `Cases`. `Growth` gives you the growth rate but it is obviously not very reliable as there are only 15 observations. So, I just took the mean of the growth rate of the last 4 observations. From there  I hypothesis that the growth rate will not be constant but will decay at a certain pace over time. This is the overall aim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to my comment above, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. If you want to model the `Growth` rate you need to fit some form of model.

For a start, how about an exponential model of the form `y = y0 * exp(k * time)`?

In that case we can linearise the model (and data) by taking the log, and then use `lm` to estimate the model coefficients `log(y0)` and `k`.

```r
df <- corona_entire %>% mutate(Time = as.integer(Date - min(Date)))
fit <- lm(log(Growth) ~ Time, weights = df$Growth, data = df)
```

Here I have used a weighted least squares approach by weighting every point by its `Growth` rate.

We can then plot the points and best fit curve:

```r
f <- function(x, fit) exp(coef(fit)[1])*exp(coef(fit)[2] * x)
ggplot(df, aes(Time, Growth)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_function(fun = f, args = list(fit = fit)) +
    labs(x = sprintf("Days since %s", min(df$Date)))
```

[image]

Not a good fit but this should give you some ideas. You probably want to fit a more suitable non-linear growth-rate model, and estimate parameters using `nls`.

---

### Update

Since you really want to predict `Cases`, let's re-formulate our model.

We start again with an exponential model of the form `Cases ~ y0 * exp(k * Time)`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Time, Cases)) +
    geom_point()
fit1 <- lm(log(Cases) ~ Time, data = df)
f1 <- function(x, fit) exp(coef(fit)[1])*exp(coef(fit)[2] * x)
ggplot(df, aes(Time, Cases)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_function(fun = f1, args = list(fit = fit1)) +
    labs(x = sprintf("Days since %s", min(df$Date)))
```

[image]

**Not a good fit!** Results seem to suggest sub-exponential growth. A simple model for sub-exponential growth in epidemiology is a model of the form `Cases ~ (r / m * Time + A)^m`, see e.g. [Chowell et al., Phys. Life Rev. 18, 66 (2016)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5348083/pdf/nihms-802148.pdf).

So let's fit the model, this time using the non-linear least-squares routine `nls`.

```r
fit2 <- nls(
    Cases ~ (r / m * Time + A)^m,
    data = df,
    start = list(r = 4, m = 3, A = 1))
f2 <- function(x, r, m, A) (r / m * x + A)^m
ggplot(df, aes(Time, Cases)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_function(
        fun = f2, 
        args = list(
            r = coef(fit2)[1],
            m = coef(fit2)[2],
            A = coef(fit2)[3])) +
    labs(x = sprintf("Days since %s", min(df$Date)))
```

[image]

Looks like a decent fit. You can inspect the quality of the fit and the non-linear least-squares estimates for the coefficients if you type `summary(fit2)`

```r
summary(fit2)
#
#Formula: Cases ~ (r/m * Time + A)^m
#
#Parameters:
#  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#r   2.3308     0.6543   3.562  0.00391 **
#m   3.3316     0.4202   7.929 4.12e-06 ***
#A   2.1101     0.3126   6.750 2.04e-05 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 51.41 on 12 degrees of freedom
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 6
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.514e-07
#
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful, I was so focused on the above perspective that I could not see this option! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rollo99 You're very welcome. Since your goal is to predict `Cases` as a function of time you probably should model `Cases` directly. I'll update my answer ...

Comment: Thanks so much. It would be even more useful rewritten to predict `Cases`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you more points as I already gave you all I could. But this is really great! Thanks a lot again! Great work and nice reference to the paper! Thanks

Comment: @Rollo99 You're very welcome. +1 for an interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a *linear* fall in growth rate towards 1 over 60 days you can do this:

```
ff = function(initial_n, initial_rate = 1.2285823, days = 60, time_to_stasis = 60)
{
  daily_rate <- seq(initial_rate, 1, length.out = time_to_stasis)
  result <- numeric(days)
  result[1] <- initial_n
  for(i in seq(days - 1)) result[i + 1] <- floor(daily_rate[i] * result[i])
  return(result)
}
```

So you get a daily number like this:

```
ff(3858)
#>  [1]    3858    4739    5803    7084    8620   10456   12643   15239   18309   21926
#> [11]   26173   31141   36932   43656   51436   60403   70699   82477   95897  111129
#> [21]  128350  147743  169494  193790  220818  250760  283791  320073  359754  402961
#> [31]  449796  500332  554607  612621  674331  739644  808418  880454  955498 1033237
#> [41] 1113297 1195248 1278600 1362812 1447290 1531398 1614460 1695773 1774611 1850239
#> [51] 1921922 1988936 2050581 2106192 2155151 2196899 2230944 2256873 2274360 2283171
```

and you can adjust the parameters to whatever you like.

You could use it to plot projections like this:

```
plot(1:60, ff(3858))
```

[image]

I'm not sure how biologically plausible this is though.

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I meant. In your code, what bit shall I change to change the pace of convergence towards 1?

Comment: Thanks,-  I just coded the method you were describing, but the method by @MauriceEvers is likely to give a more realistic result than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data, it looks like a quadratic curve is the better option to model `Cases` as a function of `days`

```
corona$days = as.numeric(corona$Date - corona$Date[1], "days") + 1
mod = lm(Cases ~ poly(days, 2, raw = TRUE), corona)
summary(mod)

#Call:
#lm(formula = Cases ~ poly(days, 2, raw = TRUE), data = corona)

#Residuals:
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#-140.48  -50.63  -24.30   65.89  148.04 

#Coefficients:
#                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)                 264.912     84.071   3.151  0.00836 ** 
#poly(days, 2, raw = TRUE)1 -158.269     24.179  -6.546 2.75e-05 ***
#poly(days, 2, raw = TRUE)2   25.863      1.469  17.600 6.17e-10 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#Residual standard error: 94.38 on 12 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.9949,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.9941 
#F-statistic:  1181 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 1.668e-14


plot(corona$days, corona$Cases)
lines(predict(mod, data.frame(days = corona$days)))

# Growth Rate 
d = predict(mod, data.frame(days = 59:60))
diff(d)/d[1]
#         2 
#0.03606188
```

Comment: running the regression part I get `Error in rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X))) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'`

Comment: yes now it works I couldn't see the first line so it didn't run. Thanks a lot. Your code is also very useful! Great material to work! thanks